# Python 3.6: get JSON from aiohttp request

Tags: json, request, http-post, python-3.6, aiohttp

I have some application which uses aiohttp.

I sent POST request into approptiate endpoint, e.g.:

```
POST mysite.com/someendpoind/
```

with data similar to:

```
{"param1": "value1", "param2": "value2", ..., "paramn": None}
```

Then on backend side, I want to add some additional conditional into this request:

```
data = await request.json()
data["additional_conditional"] = True
```

But `request.json()` fails with an error:

```
[ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 422, in start
resp = yield from self._request_handler(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiohttp/web.py", line 306, in _handle
resp = yield from handler(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiohttp_session/__init__.py", line 129, in middleware
response = yield from handler(request)
File "/opt/bikeamp/auth/__init__.py", line 57, in wrapped
return (yield from f(request, user))
File "<my_module>.py", line 185, in <my_func>
data_json = await request.json()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aiohttp/web_request.py", line 469, in json
return loads(body)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Then I decided to check somehow what is the content of my request:

```
await request.read()

b'field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3&field4=&field5=&field6='
```

So, I'm not sure, but the problem may be with empty parameters.

Also, I was trying to get this data via:

```
data = await request.post()
data["additional_condition"] = True
```

But this returns `MultiDictProxy`. Python can't pickle these objects.

Is there any known solutions?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, if post was something like `{"email": "some@email.com"}` check it with:

```
  @router('/', methods=['POST', ])
    async def post_request(request):    

        post = await request.post()
        email = post.get('email')   #  because it's MultiDict 
        logging.warning(post)       #  see post details
        logging.warning(email)      #  shows value "some@email.com" 

        json = await request.text() #
        logging.warning(json)       #  shows json if it was ajax post request
```